# How to add Input Type=Radio Values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

How do I add the values of my input type=radio(s)??
    I know I may have some mistakes in my scripts because I've just been copying them from the web. I tried to make figure out what is wrong, but I couldn't do it. I don't think this is a very difficult problem, and I may be way off, but I am still a beginner in javascript.

```
<html>

<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>function calcscore() { score = 0; $(".calc:checked").each(function () { score += Number($(this).val()); }); $("#price").text(score.toFixed(2)); $("#sum").val(score) } $().ready(function () { $(".calc").change(function () { calcscore() }); });</script>
   <style>
       table {
     width: 1000px;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
   }

   th,
   td {
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
   }

   tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Question</strong></td>
           <td><strong>1 Point</strong></td>
           <td><strong>2 Points</strong></td>
           <td><strong>4 Points</strong></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Number of Users Impacted</strong></td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="1" id="1">Single User, team or department</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="2" id="2">Multiple Users, teams or departments</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question1" value="4" id="3">All users in the organization</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Criticality of the service to the institution</strong></td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="1" id="4">If an outage occurs, core university functions
               can continue</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="2" id="5">If outage occurs, core university functions
               cannot be performed</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question2" value="4" id="6">Business critical, i.e. outage results in direct
               loss of revenue,
               reputation,
               direct exposure to fines, etc.</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Number of teams involved with implementation</strong></td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question3" value="1" id="7">Activites are limited to a single IT team</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question3" value="2" id="8">Multiple teams within IT coordinate activites</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question3" value="4" id="9">Multiple teams in different departments must
               coordinate activites</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><strong>Can it be tested? Can it be backed out?</strong></td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question4" value="1" id="10">Can it be tested and backed out easily</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question4" value="2" id="11">Either cannot be tested OR cannot be backed out
               easily</td>
           <td><input type="radio" name="Question4" value="4" id="12">Cannot be tested or backed out easily</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<center><input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Calculate" /></center>
```

I simply want my values to be added when those input radios are checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(r => {
    r.addEventListener('click', e => alert(`${e.target.name} ${e.target.value}`))
  })
```

EDIT:

```
  document.querySelector('#btnGo').addEventListener('click', e => {
    var val = 0
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(r => {
      if(r.checked) val+= parseInt(r.value, 10)
    })
    alert(val) // val is your total, do with it as you wish
  })
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but it doesn't need to alert me the "name" and I don't need to know the individual values, I need to know the total value when all of my choices are selected and I hit Calculate.

Comment: I've added your new code, but it still doesn't seem to be working. There is no "Alert" when I click calculate.

Comment: Put your script at the bottom or use `DOMContentLoaded`